# Openssl command automatically added "/openssl" before the file name in AWS nodejs that cause getting file not found error

Tags: node.js, openssl, aws-lambda

```
const openssl = require('openssl-nodejs');
await openssl('openssl base64 -d -in /tmp/omnivoltaic.signature.txt -out /tmp/encodedfile.txt',function(err,buffere){
       console.log('Err2..>>>',err.toString());
       console.log('Successs2>>>>',buffer.toString());
});
```

**Error :**

Err2..>>> openssl//tmp/omnivoltaic.signature.txt: No such file or directory
140523322107728:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('openssl//tmp/omnivoltaic.signature.txt','r')
140523322107728:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400: